# Python sort by using JSON key + prioritisation for specific value

Tags: python, json

Sample data:

```
sampleData = [{"created":""01/01/2020", "source":"a"},{"created":""01/01/2020", "source":"b"}]
```

The way I sorting this currently:

```
sorted(sampleData, key=lambda k: k["created"], reverse=True)
```

I need to make sure that IF created dates are the same the first value always will be source `b` if it does exist

What is the cleanest way to add priority?

Comment: Add a second sort that is `k["source"] == "b"`

Comment: @Sayse like this? `sorted(sampleData, key=lambda k:(k["created"],k["source"] == "b"), reverse=True)`